# Volume change effect both AVPlayer and AudioServices

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, avplayer, volume

I have both `AVPlayer` and `AudioServices` to play sound in my game.
I use `AVPlayer` for playing a background music which I do need to loop continuously, and I use `AudioServices` with soundID to play sound effects on button tap.

The problem is when I decrease the volume with iPhone side volume buttons it does affect on music play by `AVPlayer` but not on sounds which play with `AudioServices`.

What should I do to make them both play at the same volume and volume change affect on them both at same time?